# Jasper Server with Google BigQuery connection

Tags: google-bigquery, jasperserver

How we can connect Google BigQuery with Jasper Server 6.3.0 reporting tool?

Answer (score 3):

First download the [BigQuery JDBC driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/#current_jdbc_driver_releases), then follow the [JasperServer instructions for adding a JDBC driver](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v561/managing-jdbc-drivers). The relevant steps are:

1. Log on as the system administrator (superuser on commercial editions, jasperadmin on community editions).
2. Select Create > Data Source from the main menu.
3. In the Type field, select JDBC Data Source.
4. Select the installed BigQuery JDBC driver from the drop down list.